# Hive output to s3 with comma separated values and a .csv or .txt file format .An alternative like using sqoop to export from hive to s3 will also work

Tags: csv, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I ve been trying to work with hive to output to s3 . I have been successful at that but the resultant output is not comma separated but there is a delimiter such as ^A I suppose. I had also worked on using sqoop to import and export data from s3 to psql but I haven't been able to do that on hive, even if I get the solution to that it would work.

What I have tried doing is

```
set hive.io.output.fileformat=CSVTextFile; 
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "s3n://akshayhazari/results" select * from books;
```

This is the working:

```
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1403776308919_0011, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1403776308919_0011/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1403776308919_0011
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2014-06-26 16:51:07,188 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-06-26 16:51:29,868 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.95 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 950 msec
Ended Job = job_1403776308919_0011
Stage-3 is selected by condition resolver.
Stage-2 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Stage-4 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Moving data to: s3n://akshayhazari/tmp/hive-hduser/hive_2014-06-26_16-50-41_646_3052840892739735120-1/-ext-10000
Moving data to: s3n://akshayhazari/results
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.95 sec   HDFS Read: 188 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 950 msec
OK
Time taken: 55.726 seconds
```

Where as I get a file such as 000000_0 which is unreadable but after downloading it and converting it to a txt gives me ^A delimiter file. I want to get an output as a csv or txt file directly and with comma or tab separated values . Even if you are able to use INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY syntax to produce the above locally , it will be of great help as I would be able to work that on s3.

Adding detail to Original Question (This is just an added detail but the question still remains the same):  I figured what I have to do is produce a gzipped output on s3. Also minimize on the s3 usage. Where as hive puts all its temp files on S3. So to optimize usage I did this.

```
hive> SET hive.exec.compress.output=true; 
hive> SET io.seqfile.compression.type=BLOCK;
hive> SET mapred.output.compression.codec = org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
hive> Insert overwrite directory "Books" select * from books;
```

This is the Output in hdfs:

```
hduser@akshay:~$ hadoop fs -ls Books
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup        161 2014-06-27 11:45 Books/000000_0.gz
```

Then I would use this to add stuff to s3:

```
hadoop fs -cp Books/000000_0.gz s3n://akshayhazari/results
```

The output is not a text or csv and is ureadable. Even the delimiters are unreadable. Is there any work around for this in Hive or do I have to create a script to fix the file and delimiters.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Depending on which version of Hive you're using, you may be able to do:</s>

```
insert overwrite directory 's3n://akshayhazari/results'
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
select * from books;
```

I think that was added in Hive 0.11 or so.

Edit: turns out the above is only for local directories.

You can certainly also do:

```
create external table tmp_table(cols...)
location 's3n://akshayhazari/results'
row format delimited fields terminated by ',';

insert into tmp_table
select * from books;

drop table tmp_table;
```

To do pretty much the same thing but without specifying columns, you could do something like:

```
create table tmp_table(cols...)
location 's3n://akshayhazari/results'
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
as
select * from books;

alter table tmp_table set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');

drop table tmp_table;
```

create-table-as-select has the restriction that you cannot create an external table, but I think you should be able to just mark it external after the fact, and then drop it.

Comment: I have hive 0.13 and I had tried the first solution earlier but it always results in an exception  "ParseException line 1:56 cannot recognize input near 'row' 'format' 'delimited' in select clause" .

Comment: I want the other solution where cols is defined to take in parameters at runtime. But it doesn't work that way I suppose.

Comment: In Hive 0.11 a patch was added for insert overwrite local directory but not for an external directory. So it doesn't work with Insert overwrite directory. I had tried this stuff on local directory as well and it had worked then but not for s3.

Comment: Had some problems with grub on my comp so had to do stuff all over. Thanks for helping +1.That would work but I wrote a java program for it as I had to get the file format right as well as do everything in a single program Also I don't want the new table to use up additional space on my comp as the files may be in hundreds of mb or GB as well.External table will only have pointers to the data I suppose.I had to add some code to use json input as well.I used this link for help with the java program https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-RunningtheJDBCSampleCode.